# How to calculate start and end time an event in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

[image: POWER EVENTS BY AREA]

I want to calculate data in below format:

> AreaID, Power_ON_Date, Power_OFF_Date, Diff_In_Minutes

Also, I need to handle:

1. Successive entries of same event. In case of successive entries of same event with different times, need to consider only the first occurrence of the event and ignore the others.
2. Merge two rows of successive OFF and ON event into 1 row to get the desired result.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you interested in, as you have tagged 3?

Comment: Be good to see what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation  :

```
select areaid, 
       max(case when powerstatus = 'power on' then eventdatetime end) as Power_ON_Date,
       min(eventdatetime) as Power_OFF_Date,
       datediff(minute, min(eventdatetime), max(case when powerstatus = 'power on' then eventdatetime end)
               ) as diff_minute
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when powerstatus = 'power off' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by areaid order by eventdatetime) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by areaid, grp;
```

Note : `date_diff()` is for SQL Server, however you didn't any specific database. So, the function definition may different

Comment: Perfect! Thank You